# Unmet dependencies when I try to to install libreoffice writer

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, libreoffice

I try to install libreoffice writer an on my Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS. I tried it with the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install libreoffice-writer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-core
```

Unfortunately I get the system message that I've unmet dependencies. Can anyone help me? Which command I need to solve the problem.

Best regards
Christoph

Additionally i can give you the following informations:
After I give in

```
sudo apt update
```

I get back

```
OK:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
OK:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
```

Then I gave in

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

I get back

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libreoffice : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-base soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-calc soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) aber 1:7.3.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 soll installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-draw soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-impress soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-math soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-report-builder-bin soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: libreoffice-writer soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Hängt ab von: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-crosextra-caladea soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-crosextra-carlito soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-dejavu soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-linuxlibertine soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-noto-core soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-noto-extra soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-noto-ui-core soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: fonts-sil-gentium-basic soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-gnome soll aber nicht installiert werden oder
                          libreoffice-plasma soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-nlpsolver soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-report-builder soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-bsh soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-js soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-script-provider-python soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-mysql soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-wiki-publisher soll aber nicht installiert werden
               Empfiehlt: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:7.3.6~) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Finally I gave in

```
apt-cache policy libreoffice
```

I get back

```
libreoffice:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
  Versionstabelle:
     1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Can you help me?
Regards
Christoph

Comment: I think i miss package source jammy-updates.  Schau nach ob die Quelle jammy-updates bei dir in der sources.list drin is.

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows that you have disabled or deleted the source `jammy-updates`.

1. Restore the `jammy-updates` source.
2. Since your sources just changed, run `sudo apt update`
3. Try your install again: `sudo apt install libreoffice-writer`. You don't need to specify any other packages (though you can if you want).

Alternately, you could skip all those steps and install the LibreOffice snap instead: `sudo snap install libreoffice`. Note that the snap includes the entire suite of LibreOffice applications.

Advice: Try to avoid installing libreoffice using both deb and snap. It won't confuse your system at all, but the two identically-named applications --often of slightly different versions-- are very likely to confuse the human user(s).

Answer (score 0):

hello user535733,

i tried your advice and i get back the following results:

If I pursue

```
sudo apt update
```

I get back the following sources:

```
OK:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
OK:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
```

The jammy-updates are included now. But when I enter then:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-writer
```

I get still back

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libreoffice-writer : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                      Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                      Empfiehlt: libreoffice-math soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Has anyone another idea to solve this?

BR
Christoph

Comment: Try to install libreoffice-math first.  I would suggest to switch to main server.